# Php Script loaded by js loses POST

Tags: php, asp.net, post, proxy

I´ve a ASPX-Page unter www.site.com/Page.aspx. There is a PHP-Script embede sub.site.com/Script.php. These Script is embeded with javascript with

```
$('#LoadPhpScript').load("http://www.site.com/Proxy.aspx?http://sub.site.com/Script.php");
```

This works fine but with one issue. In the PHP-Script there is an Form which calls the same Script actual with action="#". But after relaoding the page the $_POST is empty. How can I send the $_POST information with the .load - Call?

Comment: The initial load will be a GET request. If I understand correctly, you want subsequent form data to pass through the same ASP.NET software proxy, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `load` only does GET requests. Use `post` or `ajax` and add the content to the page with the `success` function if you need to make a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the action attribute to an empty string. Alternatively you can populate it with the `S_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` value.

This assumes that the ASP.NET proxy will allow it ....